# Constant Bluetooth Connection Request Prompts Between Two Macs

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, catalina

I recently got a 16" MacBook Pro. My wife has a 2019 15" MacBook Pro. They're both running 10.15.1 (Software Update says both Macs are "up to date").

Ever since I got the 16" MBP both MBPs are constantly trying to connect to each other via Bluetooth:

[image]

If I ignore the prompt it goes away after two seconds. If I click check "Ignore this device" and click "Cancel" the prompt comes back after two seconds. If I click "Connect" nothing happens on either MBP and the prompt keeps appearing every few seconds.

On my wife's 15" MBP System Preferences > Bluetooth list I clicked the "X" icon next to my 16" MBP's name. After doing this a different Bluetooth device name appears in her Bluetooth list after each prompt on my MBP.

The only way I've discovered to prevent this is to turn off Bluetooth on my 16" MBP.

Any ideas on how to stop these constant Bluetooth Connection Request prompts?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with MacOS 10.15.4. I'm going to contact Apple Support

Comment: This is the most infuriating Apple bug ever!  It afflicted my daughter in the middle of an online speech & debate tournament.  Apple, which pioneered the gentle notification system (in contrast to Windows apps hitting you in the face with modal dialogs) is doing the WORST sort of interruption of their user imaginable.  It really beggars belief!

Answer (score 4):

I had a chat with Apple Support. They suggested deleting this file and rebooting the affected machines:

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist

This seems to have worked. Deleting the file does not cause any problems - it gets regenerated on startup, and all my Bluetooth devices still connect fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you hold the <kbd>option</kbd> and click the Bluetooth icon in the menubar, you can see whether your computer is discoverable by other Bluetooth devices.

Since Mavericks, Bluetooth discoverability is determined by whether you have the Bluetooth preference panel open. Other things like continuity and Bluetooth sharing might also have an effect on discoverability.

In my case, removing the Bluetooth preferences .plist file and rebooting seemed to work, but only because I didn't have the Bluetooth preference panel open after I rebooted.

Just FYI, holding shift+option and clicking the Bluetooth menubar reveals a "Debug" menu that allows you to reset some aspects of the Bluetooth system.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity and iCloud are the obvious paring agents, so I would disable handoff first on both devices and see if that quells things.

If so, you might need to engage Apple Support to see if there’s a precise way to rejigger that, but for most people you would need to sign out of iCloud on one or both Macs to then sign in again and see if the pairing identity crypto can heal itself.